# Задание FOREIGN KEY в SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite

Мой код:

```
def create_table_deputies():  
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deputies(deputy_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, faction_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(faction_id) REFERENCES factions(faction_id))""")

 def create_table_factions():
     c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS factions(faction_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT)""")

def create_table_laws():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS laws(law_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, aszdUrl TEXT, date_time DATE)""")

def create_table_votes():
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS votes(deputy_id INTEGER, vote TEXT, law_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (deputy_id) REFERENCES deputies(deputy_id), FOREIGN KEY (law_id) REFERENCES laws(law_id))""")
```

Далее идет вызов этих функций. Код компилируется, и выполняется, но, когда я смотрю на базу в  SQLite browser, связи между таблицами не видны[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Смотрим пункт 2
https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Перед созданием таблиц попробуйте включить поддержку foreignkey'ев с помощью инструкции

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

в Вашем случае, судя по всему будет нечто вроде

```
c.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")
```

Было бы неплохо уточнять, какая библиотека используется, так как судя по всему переменная `c` суть `cursor` и не стоит забывать закрывать соединение соответствующим методом, если же `cursor` является объектом класса, реализующим magic методы `__enter__` и `__exit__`, то тогда удобнее всего инициализировать его через ключевое слово `with`.

А вообще рекомендую освоить столь полезную библиотеку как [`SQLAlchemy`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/), которая позволит значительно упростить как создание, так и работу с базами данных, в числе прочих включена поддержка работы с `SQLite`.